# Regex — only zero or one 's'

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have a name, "foo bar", and in any string, `foo`, `foos`, `bar` and `bars` should be matched.

I thought this should work like this: `(foo|bar)s?`. I tried some other regexes as well, but they all were like this. How can I do this?

Comment: this is exactly what i was searching for - Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(foo|bar)s?` is correct...

You should use a boundary like `\b(foo|bar)s?\b`. Else it would also match `hihellofoos`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question seems to reflect perplexity over why you found a match in `foosss`. Note the difference between finding a match in a string, and matching the whole string.

You have several ways of dealing with this, and the right choice depends on your application.

- Anchor the regex to the whole input line or input: `^(foo|bar)s?$`
- Anchor the regex to one word: `\b(foo|bar)s?\b`
- Some APIs (but not `preg_match`) have a separate function to match the whole string.